# How to extend Shopware customer

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, shopware

I need to write a Shopware plugin that extends customer model with `external_id` field. This field should be editable through the admin UI and API.

I've found, that I can add attribute to user like so:

```
public function addAttributes() {
    $this->Application()->Models()->addAttribute(
        's_user_attributes',
        'bla',
        'externalId',
        'INT(11)',
        true,
        null
    );

    $this->Application()->Models()->generateAttributeModels(array(
        's_user_attributes'
    ));
}
```

What should I do to show this field in the UI and API?

**PS: Shopware 5**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the backend you have to to do some [ExtJs coding](http://community.shopware.com/Schuhgroessen-Erweiterung_detail_1052_871.html#Erweiterung_des_Backend-Moduls).

For the API you have to extend the [REST-API endpoint for the user](http://community.shopware.com/REST-API-Kunden-Endpunkt_detail_1687.html):

[Shopware API erweitern](http://community.shopware.com/Shopware-4-API-erweitern_detail_991.html)

Comment: The 2nd link ain't valid anymore. This is why you post full code reference and not just links!

Answer (score 5):

`addAttribute` is deprecated in Shopware 5.
Use `shopware_attribute.crud_service` from the `Shopware()`-container instead.

```
$service = Shopware()->Container()->get('shopware_attribute.crud_service');
$service->update('s_user_attributes', 'bla', 'integer', [
    'label' => '',
    'supportText' => '',
    'helpText' => '',
    'translatable' => false,
    'displayInBackend' => true,
    'position' => 1
]);

Shopware()->Models()->generateAttributeModels(
    array(
        's_user_attributes'
    )
);
```

If you set `displayInBackend` to `true`, you can edit it in the Backend, where the user is.

More at the [Shopware Developer Guide](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/).